# DataTable with .Net5

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I tried to use datatable with my project and I always got undefined when data return from the controller while I checked the controller already returned 1000 records
this is my controller

```
   [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult get_Student_Info()
    {
                    var model = (from C in _db1.ClassesInfos
                     select new Classes
                     {
                         ClassId = C.Id,
                         ClassCounty = C.ClassCounty ?? "",
                         ClassLocation = C.ClassLocation,
                         ClassSize = C.ClassSize ?? 0,
                         ClassDate = C.ClassDate.ToString(),
                         //ClassMonitorId = C.MonitorId,
                         //ClassActive = C.Active ?? 0,
                         //ClassLastModifedDate = C.LastModifiedDate.ToString(),
                         //ClassPasscode = C.Passcode,
                         //ClassType = C.ClassType

                     }).FirstOrDefault();
                    
         return Json(mymodel, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and this is my view

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        //url: "/Instructor/get_Student_Info",
        url: '@Url.Action("get_Student_Info", "Instructor")',
        mimeType: 'json',
        async: true,
              
             success: function(data) {
                 $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                     alert(data.ClassCounty);
                     alert(data.ClassLocation);
                     
               
        var body = "<tr>";
                     body += "<td>" + data.ClassCounty + "</td>";
                     body += "<td>" + data.ClassLocation + "</td>";
     
        body    += "</tr>";
        $( "#ClasssInfo tbody" ).append(body);
    });
    /*DataTables instantiation.*/
       $( "#ClasssInfo" ).DataTable();
},
       
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi @Luay Almamury, your `model` is just return one record, and what you return is `mymodel`. Please share the correct message. Besides `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is used in asp.net mvc instead of asp.net core/.net 5. Which one is your real used? If your backend code just return one record, no need use `each` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In asp.net mvc**, it should be:

Model:

```
public class Class
{
    public string ClassCounty { get; set; }
    public string ClassLocation { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<table id="ClasssInfo">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ClassCounty</th>
            <th>ClassLocation</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
@section Scripts
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("get_Student_Info", "Home")",
            mimeType: 'json',
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#ClasssInfo").DataTable({
                    data: data,
                    columns: [{ 'data': 'ClassCounty' },
                        { 'data': 'ClassLocation' }]
                });
            },

        });

    });

    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult get_Student_Info()
{
    //must be list model
    var model = new List<Class>(){
        new Class()
        {
            ClassCounty = "aa",
            ClassLocation = "location"
        }
    };
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**In asp.net core/.net 5**, it should be:

View:

Note: In asp.net core/.net 5, the response json format is **camel case**.

```
<table id="ClasssInfo">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ClassCounty</th>
            <th>ClassLocation</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
@section Scripts
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("get_Student_Info", "Home")",
            mimeType: 'json',
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#ClasssInfo").DataTable({
                    data: data,
                    columns: [{ 'data': 'classCounty' },   //difference here..should be camel case
                        { 'data': 'classLocation' }]
                });
            },

        });

    });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult get_Student_Info()
{
    var model = new List<Class>(){
        new Class()
        {
            ClassCounty = "aa",
            ClassLocation = "location"
        }
    };

    return Json(model);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I figure that issue with JSON camel case.

Comment: Just did. Thank you.